# Power Supply 550W

Tags: desktop, power-supply

I have the following system: i5 8400, MSI B360 Gaming Plus, 16GB of DDR4 (2x8), GTX1050 Ti, 4 case fans (3 of them powered at 5V and one from the MB), CM Hyper 212 Evo, 1 SSD, 1 HDD, 1 ODD. 
I need a new power supply because the actual one is dying. I will also get a new GPU (probably a GTX1660 Ti or RTX2060), and one or 2 more SSD's or HDD's. 
My current power supply is a Sirtec High Power 600W Bronze.

Which from the following should be OK for my system:
Seasonic Focus GX, 80+ Gold, 550W or
 Super Flower SF-550F14MT, 550W 80+ Silver ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact power draw for your system right now so I can't post this as an answer; Depending on whether 550W is enough, either power supply will be OK.

Comment: If you want to find a good power supply for purchase you can enter all your cpu specs and [PC Part Picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/) is capable of calculating the Wattage requirements for you. I rarely end up doing the calculations manually as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Either of those power supplies should meet your needs, and Seasonic and Super Flower are both respectable manufacturers.  With no strong reason to pick one over the other, I'd recommend the Seasonic simply because 80+ Gold is slightly more energy-efficient than 80+ Silver.